# Handle/Prevent NullReferenceException in MVC5 View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, nullreferenceexception, entity-framework-6

I have a View which is using [Grid.MVC](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/) to display desired User Properties. My controller below, uses the User [MemberOrgID] or [SponsorOrgID] to find the all the relevant Org/Sponsor information related to that users particular ID (User will have an ID for one of the other, never both):

```
    // GET: Admin/UserManagement
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        ViewBag.headerTitle = "User Management";
        ViewBag.showCreateButton = true;
        ViewBag.createUrl = "/Admin/UserManagement/Create";
        ViewBag.createText = " Create a New User";
        List<ApplicationUser> model = UserManager.Users.ToList();
        foreach (ApplicationUser user in model)
        {
            if (user.MemberOrgId != null)
            {
                user.Organization = db.MemberOrganizations.Find(user.Organization);
            }
            //else
            //{
            //    user.Organization.Name = " ";
            //}

            if (user.SponsorOrgId != null)
            {
                user.Sponsor = db.SponsorOrganizations.Where(o => o.Id == user.SponsorOrgId).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            //else
            //{
            //    user.Sponsor.Name = " ";
            //}
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Since my first User has a Sponsor ID, this is what I can see within the Immediate Window while debugging in VS2013:

```
?user.Sponsor
    {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SponsorOrganizations_F2A27693F33AFF36C814F6FFA2CE63AD656938244F599B7D1AB2ED80CC26EF9A}
    [System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SponsorOrganizations_F2A27693F33AFF36C814F6FFA2CE63AD656938244F599B7D1AB2ED80CC26EF9A]: {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SponsorOrganizations_F2A27693F33AFF36C814F6FFA2CE63AD656938244F599B7D1AB2ED80CC26EF9A}
    City: null
    Country: null
    Enabled: true
    FacebookUrl: "https://www.facebook.com/sponsor1"
    Id: 1
    LogoSrc: "Sponsor1.jpg"
    Name: "Sponsor1"
    OwnerId: "1d720c20-a508-4880-a5e6-80af5f2f8caf"
    OwnerName: "Sponsor Primary"
    ProfilePictureUrl: "sponsorprofilepicture/Sponsor1.jpg"
    SponsorServiceCategory: Count = 11
    State: null
    TwitterUrl: "https://twitter.com/sponsor1"
    Users: Count = 0
    WebsiteUrl: "http://www.sponsor1.com"
```

I am having a NullReference Issue however as when the View is loaded (below) the code `o.Organization.Name` is flagged as a `NullReferenceException` (I have added a try catch just to make things a little friendlier and let the rest of the View load):

```
@using GridMvc.Html
@model IEnumerable<PROJECTS.Models.ApplicationUser>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View Users";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";

}

<div class="overflowPrevention">
    <!-- Grid.MVC Code -->
    <div>
        @*Images in Columns: https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/discussions/440977*@
@try
{ 
        @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "UserManagement", new { id = o.Id }, null)).SetWidth(15);
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => o.Name).Titled("Name").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(100);
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => o.Position).Titled("Position").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(50);
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => o.Email).Titled("Email").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(100);
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => o.EmailConfirmed.ToString()).Titled("Confirmed").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(100);
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => o.MemberOrgId.ToString()).Titled("MemOrg.").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(25);
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => o.Organization.Name.ToString()).Titled("MemOrg.").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(25);
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => o.SponsorOrgId.ToString()).Titled("Sponsor").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(25);
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => o.Sponsor.Name.ToString()).Titled("Sponsor").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(25);
        }).WithPaging(5)
}
catch (NullReferenceException ex)
{
    return;
}
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have thoughts on how I might negate this `NullReferenceException` issue? The User will always have either a MemberOrganizationID or SponsorID, meaning that either the `o.Organization.Name` will have a value or `o.Sponsor.Name` will, but never both. I'm trying to find a way to make the one which is null either not show up, or just appear as a blank value within the column.

Any help greatly appreciated! I've attempted to negate this issue through some `IF` checks on my Controller as well as some code on the View but haven't yet found a solution.

**EDIT:**

Chris' solution worked! Below is my updated code segments:

```
foreach (ApplicationUser user in model)
        {
            if (user.MemberOrgId != null)
            {
                user.Organization = db.MemberOrganizations.Where(o => o.Id == user.MemberOrgId).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            if (user.SponsorOrgId != null)
            {
                user.Sponsor = db.SponsorOrganizations.Where(o => o.Id == user.SponsorOrgId).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
        return View(model);

        columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => o.MemberOrgId.ToString()).Titled("MemOrgID").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(25);
        columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => o.Organization == null ? "" : o.Organization.Name.ToString()).Titled("MemOrg Name.").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(25);
        columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => o.SponsorOrgId.ToString()).Titled("SponsorID").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(25);
        columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => o.Sponsor == null ? "" : o.Sponsor.Name.ToString()).Titled("Sponsor Name").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(25);
```

Comment: I've seen that post before Daniel. I thought this may be slightly different as I know why and how I am getting `Null` exception, but am trying to find a way around it. Chris has found the Answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for a null Organization before trying to get the name?

```
columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false)
    .RenderValueAs(o => o.Organization == null ? "" : o.Organization.Name.ToString())
    .Titled("MemOrg.").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(25);
```

If you want to combine them into a single column, modify the above code to return the sponsor name if the organization is null.

Comment: Thanks for replying Chris! I've tried something similar before, but when I do `columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => o.Organization ? o.Organization.Name.ToString() : "").Titled("MemOrg.").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(25);` the `o.Organization` after `o =>` is flagged as: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'PROJECT.Models.MemberOrganizations' to 'bool'".

Comment: Sorry, javascript snuck through.  The example has been modified

Comment: That did the trick, thank you so much Chris! That is exactly what I was attempting to do but was having quite the time nailing down the syntax.